# Meaning of the Potter in forming the Clay

Tags: jeremiah

What does Jeremiah 18 mean when it says the clay was marred in the hands of the potter? It sounds like it was the fault of the potter.

Comment: Please could you quote and reference the text you wish to analyse. Please could you add some explanation of what you are looking for in that text. Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: On my screen the [Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) is accessed from the right side of the top bar. I see  only now it also can be found at the bottom of the page!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking of this passage:

> This is the word that came to Jeremiah from the Lord: 2 “Go down to the potter’s house, and there I will give you my message.” 3 So I went down to the potter’s house, and I saw him working at the wheel. **4 But the pot he was shaping from the clay was marred in his hands; so the potter formed it into another pot, shaping it as seemed best to him.**

The sense is not that the potter intentionally disfigured the clay, but the clay slackened in his hand. The analogy draws over to the nation of Israel.

> 5 Then the word of the Lord came to me. 6 He said, “Can I not do with you, Israel, as this potter does?” declares the Lord. “Like clay in the hand of the potter, so are you in my hand, Israel. **7 If at any time I announce that a nation or kingdom is to be uprooted, torn down and destroyed, 8 and if that nation I warned repents of its evil, then I will relent and not inflict on it the disaster I had planned. 9 And if at another time I announce that a nation or kingdom is to be built up and planted, 10 and if it does evil in my sight and does not obey me, then I will reconsider the good I had intended to do for it.**

Answer (score 1):

The allegory of the Potter and the clay, described in Jeremiah 18:1-12,  tells of the ignorance of Israelites, who as the Lord's creation, wanted to overrule their Creator.

One has to be careful, when reading an allegory/parable in the Bible, the focus is always on the story development. Focus should not be on the characters for they would not be perfectly matching. For example, the potter here is posted as the creator but surely his capability did not match the Creator.

In the beginning of the story, the Lord asked Jeremiah to go to a potter's house without telling him why. The potter in the story is described as the creator of clay product, which was his creation. He found the clay didn't fit for his original plan, so he shaped it as another that was suited for its quality (Jer 18:4).

Subsequently, the Lord explained to Jeremiah that He is the sovereign Lord of Israel (Jer 18:6-10), He wished the Israelites to repent, though He knew it was in vain (Jer 18:11)

> 12 But they (Israelites) will reply, ‘It’s no use. We will continue with our own plans; we will all follow the stubbornness of our evil hearts.’” (Jer 18:12)

**Verse 12 reflected the ignorance of the Israelites, who as a creation, wanted to overrule their Creator's will.**

Comment: you may not have the right word when you say "sarcasm." The rest of the answer is good.

Comment: @DanFefferman - I did escalate the tone. What word would you suggest

Comment: @DanFefferman - I edited my answer that should be more neutral.

Comment: @Vincent Wong. Forgive me if I interfered with your answer in a wrong way. I only wanted  to make grammar suggestions.

Comment: @C.Stroud - you are welcome to help

Answer (score 1):

I have upvoted James Adijuah's answer, but I would add this:

The the analogy of the pot, like all analogies, is not perfect because clay has no free will, as we do and Israel did. So technically, the OP is correct in its concern. The potter has not plied his craft well if the clay "slackens" - but the analogy does not imply that the fault is God's in relation to Israel.

The prophet makes this clear. Israel has behaved irresponsibly and be punished accordingly.

> Now, therefore, say to the people of Judah and the inhabitants of
> Jerusalem: Thus says the Lord: Look, I am a potter shaping evil
> against you and devising a plan against you. Turn now, all of you,
> from your evil way, and amend your ways and your doings. (18:11)

**A final point, although God "shapes evil" for Israel here, it is important that the pot is not absolutely destroyed but reshaped. The clay is the same clay, and the pot will still be a pot as the designer intended. Israel will remain Israel, but will be reformed. This applies whether we interpret the prophecy as relating to the historical Israel after it returned from exile, or to the "new Israel" of Christianity.**

Answer (score 0):

A skilled artist will often refine his/her creation over time.  Our Father created us with free will, therefore limiting His own sovereignty. Rather, He has opted to mold us into His image through love and discipline when needed. Scripture speaks of a refiner's fire.

God created everything with earth and water by His Breath/Spirit.  Like a potter, He molded His creation as He saw pleasurable and beautiful. He continues to refine His creation today.

Its not that He marred His creation... NO.  His creation was marred/corrupted while in His hands due to a disobedient free will choice.

The scripture below shows the Father acts according to the free will of His creation.   His omnipotence allows for His choice to not have omniscience in things yet to be decided.  He is the beginning and the end... what is in between is mostly left up to free will.

Jer 18

> 5 Then the word of the Lord came to me, saying, 6 O house of Israel, cannot I do with you as this potter? saith the Lord. Behold, as the clay is in the potter's hand, so are ye in mine hand, O house of Israel.  7 At what instant I shall speak concerning a nation, and concerning a kingdom, to pluck up, and to pull down, and to destroy it;  8 If that nation, against whom I have pronounced, turn from their evil, I will repent of the evil that I thought to do unto them.  9 And at what instant I shall speak concerning a nation, and concerning a kingdom, to build and to plant it; 10 If it do evil in my sight, that it obey not my voice, then I will repent of the good, wherewith I said I would benefit them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that God's sovereignty is not limited. He gave us free will,and our decisions affect our destiny.  Sometimes it's not what God planned,and so He had to reshape us to fit His plan and Purpose. Blessings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).